# How to add a DNS record

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

How do I add a record for my Exchange server in local DNS (mail.domain.cm) to point to my server? (It keeps wanting to append FQDN on the end of the domain).

I'm using Windows DNS service on Server 2003. I'm trying to get internal clients to resolve the mail. The problem I am getting is [shown here](http://www.shudnow.net/2007/08/10/outlook-2007-certificate-error/).

Comment: And what, pray tell, DNS software are you running?

Comment: 2003 server sp1

Comment: Add a dot (`.`) at the end.

Comment: And I assuming the FQDN is being added to the end, not the start.

Comment: @mike yes sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding an A record to one of your already created Forward Lookup Zones, then it will add the FQDN to the record, since you are adding an A record into that zone.

If you want to use a completely different domain name, add a new Forward Lookup Zone: right click on Forward Lookup Zones and click New Zone. Using the wizard, create a new primary zone called 'domain.cm' (without quotes). Once it's created, open the zone and add a 'mail' A record with the server's IP.

Comment: Ultimately, this question boiled down to the SAN on my SSL cert. Because the naming was mismatched on my internal FQDN, I thought I was missing a DNS record internally. Thank you guys very much, sorry for the misconstrued question.

Answer (score 2):

For mail, you should probably ad an MX-record. Something along these lines:
[image: Adding MX record]

Comment: my mx records are hosted, create one anyway?

Comment: Uhu.Add an A-record for mail.domain.com. -> IP of Exchange, then add an MX-record with priority 10 and mail.domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a dot to the Hostname like In MX mydomain.com. to prevent it from adding the FQDN to the host.

Comment: then it just says hostname invalid...